# Stock many "subFolders" in SQL ? how to do it?

Tags: sql, node.js

Recently, I think what is the best way to stock many subFolders with SQL and what kind of tables structures ? I explain you:

I have a user todolist application, he can create many or just one todo :
-buy bread
-call mom
etc...

My structure in SQL to save :

```
 - USER Table 
 - ID: 1
 - Name: bob

 - TODO Table
 - ID: 1
 - Value: call mom
 - UserId: 1
```

That is simple, now my user bob want to create folders (many folders...) as much as he wants and last folder, there will be todo, I show you :

```
  - Morning (folder)
    - 08:00am (folder)
      - take breakfast (todo)
      - brushing your teeth (todo)
    - 10:00am(folder)
      - take a shower (todo)
      - go to work (todo)
```

it's a simple example, but potentially the user can to create folder in folder in folder etc and the last folder the todo, like that :

```
 - MainFolder 
  - subfolder
   - subfolder
    - subfolder
     - todo 1
     - todo 2
     - todo 3
```

I don't know how stock this structure type... how create my tables, mainId ? subId ? todoId ?
I am not expert in SQL and if someone can i to help me or just give a clue haha

thanks!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a table for your folders and give them a column to identify thier parent folder or set the value to null if they don't have one like this

```
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
| folder_id | folder_name | parent_folder |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
|         1 | Morning     | null          |
|         2 | 08:00am     | 1             |
|         3 | 10:00am     | 1             |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
```

Then you could add another table for your todos and specify in which parent folder your todo is

```
+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| todo_id | folder_id |      todo_name      |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+
|       1 |         2 | take breakfast      |
|       2 |         2 | brushing your teeth |
|       3 |         3 | take a shower       |
|       4 |         3 | go to work          |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Now each folder can have a parent and each todo needs a folder (foreign key = folder_id). If you setup your table correctly (`ON DELETE CASCADE`) everytime you delete a folder all todos should be deleted as well